# EGit: resurrecting a project after deleting it

Tags: eclipse, git, workflow, egit

Say I use EGit to work with a GitHub project.  I clone the repo to my local machine, and then check the project out from my local repo (master branch) into an Eclipse project.

I do some work, commit & push my changes, and voila - I'm done. I close the project, then delete it from my Eclipse workspace.

A year later, I need to resume working on the same project. In that time, a lot has happened to it (from other people pushing changes to master).

Still being brand new to git (let alone EGit & GitHub), my initial inclination is to see if I can just fetch all the new changes to my local master from the GitHub (original) master, and then check out master into a new Eclipse project.  So my first question is: **is this a correct assumption, or am I way off base (if so, how)?**

Assuming this is a correct assumption, then from inside Eclipse/EGit, how do I properly:

1. Fetch/pull all the changes (via EGit) to my local repo's master branch, so that it is now in synch with what the GitHub master branch has?; and how do I then...
2. Checkout the project (via EGit) so that my new project is in synch with my local repo's master?

And again, if this is not the correct approach, what is?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, just import the project into Eclipse using *Import* > *Existing Projects into Workspace*. With a sufficiently new version of EGit, the project should automatically be detected to be in a Git repository. If not, then open the context menu of the project and select *Team* > *Share Project...*. Then execute *Team* > *Pull*.